# How to get the list of open windows from xserver

Tags: x11, xserver

Anyone got an idea how to get from an Xserver the list of all open windows?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

From the CLI you can use

```
xwininfo -tree -root
```

If you need to do this within your own code then you need to use the `XQueryTree` function from the `Xlib` library.

Comment: I would mod this up twice if I could!

Comment: This is great for listing the windows. I now wonder if there is a command that would force closing a specific window

Answer (score 21):

If your window manager implements EWMH specification, you can also take a look at the `_NET_CLIENT_LIST` value of the root window. This is set by most modern window managers:

```
xprop -root|grep ^_NET_CLIENT_LIST
```

That value can easily be obtained programmatically, see your Xlib documentation!

Comment: I like this; it is consistently faster than xwininfo or xdotool (though xdotool can easily exclude visible windows).

Comment: No need for grep: `xprop -root _NET_CLIENT_LIST`

Answer (score 15):

Building off of [Marten's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1017932/11411686), (assuming your window manager supports **E**xtended **W**indow **M**anager **H**ints) you can feed that list of window ids back into `xprop` to get the `_NET_WM_NAME` property:

```sh
$ xprop -root _NET_CLIENT_LIST |
    pcregrep -o1 '# (.*)' |
    sed 's/, /\n/g' |
    xargs -I{} -n1 xprop -id {} _NET_WM_NAME
```

But at the command line, it would just be easier to use `wmctrl`:

```sh
$ wmctrl -l
```

Programmatically, with `python-xlib`, you can do the same with:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Xlib.display import Display
from Xlib.X import AnyPropertyType

display = Display()
root = display.screen().root

_NET_CLIENT_LIST = display.get_atom('_NET_CLIENT_LIST')
_NET_WM_NAME = display.get_atom('_NET_WM_NAME')

client_list = root.get_full_property(
    _NET_CLIENT_LIST,
    property_type=AnyPropertyType,
).value

for window_id in client_list:
    window = display.create_resource_object('window', window_id)
    window_name = window.get_full_property(
        _NET_WM_NAME,
        property_type=AnyPropertyType,
    ).value
    print(window_name)
```

Or, better yet, using the `EWMH` library:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from ewmh import EWMH

window_manager_manager = EWMH()
client_list = window_manager_manager.getClientList()

for window in client_list:
    print(window_manager_manager.getWmName(window))
```

Comment: I like the ease of **EWMH** module however I'm abbreviating `window_manager_manager` object name to `wm`. Also I received an error on **xlib** example line `property_type=AnyPropertyType` that readsi: ***TypeError: get_full_property() got an unexpected keyword argument 'property_type'***

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix why I called it that eludes me now, lol. And it's weird that you're getting that error. I just pulled out my Linux laptop to test the script and it ran without an issue for me, but perhaps we're using different versions of `python-xlib`? In any case, if you just remove the `property_type=` part, it should work as a positional argument.